# Laravel int a binario de 32 bits (y viceversa)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, binario

En un intento de crear una columna con números binarios de 32 bits

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->char('binary_number', 32)->charset('binary'); // Em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615777/5675325
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Cabe destacar

```
$table->char('binary_number', 32)->charset('binary');
```

Cuando lo veo a través de HeidiSQL puedo ver que es de tipo `BINARY` con tamaño 32.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Al crear el sembrador para popular con los datos deseados, probé

```
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
   DB::table('teams')->insert([
    'id' => 1,
    'binary_number' => 2,
    'created_at' => now(),
    'updated_at' => now()
    ]);
```

Resulta que si utilizo 2 o 101 en `binary_number`, conseguiré que el resultado en la BD sea 2 o 101, respectivamente.

Cuando pruebo `00000000000000000000000000000010` (que equivale a 2 en binario de 32 bits) y `0000000000000000000001100101` (que equivale a 101 en binario de 32 bits)

```
'binary_number' => 00000000000000000000000000000010,
```

entonces obtengo los valores 8 y 294977, respectivamente.

Sin embargo, lo que busco es que el 2 se almacene como `000000000000000000000000000000000010` y el 101 como `00000000000000000000010000100101`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66814465/5675325)

> Lo que estás viendo es que el número está codificado en base 8, esto es porque lo estás prefijando con un 0 (seguido de más 0s) lo que hace que 010 base 8 == 8 base 10.
>
> En PHP para indicar que un número es binario `0b10`, por lo que su código sería:
>
> `'binary_number' => 0b00000000000000000000000000000010, // this is2 in decimal`
>
> Si quieres que el número decimal 10 se almacene en la base de datos, sólo tienes que utilizar
>
> `'binary_number' => 10,`
>
> Ten en cuenta que parece que la traducción a binario se realiza al final de la base de datos, por lo que no necesitas pasar el número binario si no lo quieres.
>
> Si quiere forzar el número a una cadena binaria de la longitud dada, puede utilizar
>
> `$binaryString = str_pad(base_convert(2, 10,  2),32,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);  // '00000000000000000000000000000010'`
>
> Para más detalles -
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php